# ack command didn't return output from current directory in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ack

(edited) 
Let say i have some directory structure like this:

```
lv1_directory
|  file_contain_word_something.txt
|  lv2_directory
```

so now i'm at lv2_directory and i have a code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
findfile=$(ack -n 'something' . | wc -l)
cd ..
ls
echo $findfile
```

when i run the script it give me

```
lv2_directory            file_contain_word_something.txt
0
```

but if i didn't assign it to variable it work like charm

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
ls
ack -n 'something' | wl -l
```

it give me

```
lv2_directory            file_contain_word_something.txt
1
```

so i have to change it to this to work

```
#!/bin/bash
findfile=$(ack -n 'something' .. | wc -l)
cd ..
ls  
echo $findfile
```

it give me the result i want

```
lv2_directory            file_contain_word_something.txt
1
```

How can i use the first script and give me the result i want?

Comment: The first script has broken logic. It first runs `ack` and then changes the directory. These two operations need always to be in the order `change directory` then `run ack`.

Comment: This is why you should always Edit->Run->Post instead of Run->Edit->Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is:

You are currently inside `lv2_directory` which **DOES NOT HAVE** any file which matches the string `'something'`. So when you fire `ack` from this dir itself, you get `0` for number of lines. Then you do `cd..`.

```
#!/bin/bash
findfile=$(ack -n 'something' . | wc -l)
cd ..
ls
echo $findfile
```

Now, in your next snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
ls
ack -n 'something' | wl -l
```

You are first doing `cd`, so you are into `lv1_directory`, which has the file `file_contain_word_something.txt`. Then you fire your `ack`. Now it finds `something` in the `txt` file and hence, gives you `1` as the output(assuming there's only 1 matching line).

Answer (score 0):

Like you wrote your script, it will never list (**ls** instruction), and count (**wc** instruction) in the same directory, so you have no result guarantee.

In addition, according to the directory in which you will launch the script, it may not work at all.

May you consider managing path at beginning of your script (and don't modify it between your instructions)?

Do you exactly know where is it on the system?
An alternative, may be to create an environment variable (for instance in your  **~/.bash_profile** file), and to use it at beginning of your script, ensuring it'll always be run in the good directory.

Answer (score 0):

after some experiment i can achieve the result i want using function

```
#!/bin/bash
function findfile(){
    ack -n 'something' | wc -l
}

cd ..
findfile
```

and its gonna give you `1`

thank you for answering my question